# git push isn't syncing worktree directory

Tags: git

I'm working on a locale repository `$HOME/some_git_repo`
Now, i must do `git checkout` on the server side, everytime i need to push anything updated. (i can handle that).

The problem is that isn't synchronizing anything in the `/var/www/some_git_repo`, on the server side (remote).
That means the `hooks/post_receive` script isn't doing their work

scope:

```
# post-receive  -- script
git --work-tree='/var/www/some_git_repo' --git-dir='/var/repo/some_git_repo.git'
```

Comment: There's not enough information in your question to be sure what's going wrong. Clearly the deployment post-receive script has a bug, but you have not shown us that script, or its setup (permissions, etc).

Comment: The line above, shows enterily the `post-receive` scripts as it is. No more lines are in there.

Comment: `$ ls -l hooks/post-receive: -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 93 Oct 31 14:08`. Please ask for what specific info you do need, because i'm not undertanding to you either.

Comment: There are two lines above, with the word `scope:` in front of them. Do you mean that the second line, with `git --work-tree=...`, is the only line of the script? (In which case, why is `post-receive  -- script` quoted like that?)

Comment: yes, that was my fault. Sorry i must admit it is confusing. But that first line is not part of the code. The script have just only the second line. I edited the line and save it as commented line.

Comment: The script post-receive have only this line: `git --work-tree=/var/www/some_git_repo --git-dir='/var/repo/some_git_repo.git checkout -f `

Comment: OK, then I believe I know what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this response is not the preferible solution, but it resolve the problem,
by updating the working-tree with a simple executable script:

```
rsync -arv --exclude=something_tobe_excluded \
  --progress repo_source-dir working_tree
```

Every file/directory_path, must be specified as a single argument. (on the `exclude` variable).

Answer (score 1):

#### TL;DR summary: add a `#!` line at the top

I assume your post-receive script is in fact just the single line:

```
git --work-tree=/var/www/some_git_repo --git-dir=/var/repo/some_git_repo.git checkout -f
```

(I note that this, from [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40346046/git-push-isnt-syncing-worktree-directory?noredirect=1#comment68005134_40346046), is slightly different from what was in your original posting, having `checkout -f` at the end of the line; I've also removed some unnecessary quote marks, one of which was missing in the comment version).

Your OS also appears to be Linux or Solaris or some Unix-like variant, based on the permissions you describe in [another comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40346046/git-push-isnt-syncing-worktree-directory?noredirect=1#comment68004053_40346046):

```
$ ls -l hooks/post-receive
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 93 Oct 31 14:08
```

The script *is* set to be executable, which is necessary, but is not *sufficient*: it needs to be *marked* executable (and is), but it also needs to be *actually* executable (and is not).  That is, the underlying operating system must recognize this as a program that can be run without assistance.

Command-line interpreters (aka *shells*) like `/bin/sh` and `/bin/bash` use different rules than the underlying OS.  If a file is marked executable, but the OS is unable to run it on its own, these command-line interpreters apply a fallback.  They will treat the script as a shell script, and run it themselves.  They will, for instance, tell the OS to run `/bin/sh`, with the script as an *argument* to `/bin/sh`.  Git does not do this: it relies on the program being *directly executable by the OS*.

(Which shell is the fall-back interpreter?  That's up to the shell you are running, since it's that very shell doing the fall-back.)

Fortunately, all modern Unix-like OSes provide a way to allow the OS to run the script directly.  Simply write the script using *at least* two lines (more are of course permitted) with the *first* line having the form:

```
#! /bin/sh
```

or:

```
#! /bin/bash
```

or:

```
#! /usr/local/bin/bash
```

or wherever the appropriate command-line-interpreter itself lives.  (You can run `which sh` or `type sh` to find out where the `sh` interpreter lives, or `which bash` or `type bash` to find out where the `bash` interpreter lives, and so on.  For instance, on one of my machines I get:

```
$ which sh
/bin/sh
$ type sh
sh is /bin/sh
$ which bash
/usr/local/bin/bash
$ type bash
bash is /usr/local/bin/bash
```

while another gives me:

```
sh-3.2$ which sh
/bin/sh
sh-3.2$ type sh
sh is /bin/sh
sh-3.2$ which bash
/bin/bash
sh-3.2$ type bash
bash is /bin/bash
```

which shows that not every interpreter winds up in the same location on every machine.)

This first line makes the program *directly* executable by the OS: the OS locates the appropriate interpreter and runs that interpreter, passing the name of the script as an argument (just as the shells do themselves).

Note that this means you can use *any* program as the interpreter.  An awk script can begin with:

```
#! /usr/bin/awk
```

A Python script can begin with:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
```

You can run Ruby scripts this way as well.  You can also solve the problem that the interpreters live in different locations on different machines by using `/usr/bin/env`, which tends *not* to move around (so that it's always in `/usr/bin`) but also applies the `PATH` environment variable:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
```

This locates the Python interpreter, whether it's /usr/bin/python or /usr/local/bin/python, automatically through `$PATH`.  (Of course it's critical that `$PATH` be set, but it nearly always *is*.)

#### Long unnumbered footnote: fun with scripting

If you have ever wondered *why* scripts have these `#!` lines at the top, now you know.  But they can do more than just make `sh` scripts directly executable.

This is a self-printing script:

```
#! /bin/cat
I print myself!
```

The OS runs this by invoking `/bin/cat` on the name of the script.  The `cat` command prints the contents of the script to standard output, and exits.  The one minor annoyance is that the `#!` line itself gets printed, so we fix this using `/bin/sed`:

```
#! /bin/sed 1d
I print myself too,
and I elide my first line.
```

The OS passes the `1d` as an argument before the name of the script.  Since `/bin/sed` treats its first argument as an editing command, and the second argument as the input file, this deletes the first line before copying to the output stream, then prints the remaining lines (`sed`'s default action is to print a line).

This is a self-*removing* script:

```
#! /bin/rm -f
```

It has no function other than being entertaining.  You can run it once, and then it's gone.

Some OSes allow multiple arguments after the interpreter, while others allow only one argument, effectively quoting remaining white space.  You can tell which kind of OS you have by using a self-"awk"-ing script that works if and only if the entire command is one `argv` element:

```
#! /bin/awk NR > 1 { print }
only one argument is passed
```

When the OS invokes `/bin/awk`, it either does this as the shell equivalent of:

```
/bin/awk 'NR > 1 { print }' /path/to/script
```

which prints all but the first line, *or* it runs it as the shell equivalent of:

```
/bin/awk NR '>' 1 { print } /path/to/script
```

which causes a complaint from awk:

```
awk: can't open file >
 source line number 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your accurate answer. But the problem still the same. It is possible that i was doing something wrong. If it is my fault i can't see the error. And yes, i tryed `#!/bin/bash` and `#!/bin/sh`. Now i'm syncing by "hand". But thx any way, the response is very usefull.

Comment: As a debug technique, you can put an `echo test` or similar in your script. If you see it on `git push` (it should come out as `remote: test`) you know your script is running, and if you do not see it, you know your script is not running.

Comment: Thats a good idea, i'll try that. Another question, i must include the `post-rexeive` script on the client/server `.gitignore`?

Comment: I added that on the client `post-receeive` script copy. Nothing was showed when pushed. I'm proceding with `git checkout --detach` on the server side before pushing from "locale".

Comment: Git doesn't source-control anything underneath `.git` in the first place, so putting `.git/hooks/post-receive` in `.gitignore` has no effect. The lack of output indicates that the post-receive script is still not running; at this point it's not clear why.

Comment: Thx, that clarify some things!